# Caesar Cipher Issue in Regards to Caesar Cipher in Python

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

My decode function works correctly, but my encode function is all good until the last letter. When worked out it should display "uryyb" for hello but instead it "uryyl". Here is my code:

```
def encode(w, o):

    result = ""
    w = w.lower()

    for i in w:
        letter = ord(i)
        if ord('a') <= letter <= ord('z'):
            new_letter = letter + (o % 26)
            if new_letter < 26:
                new_letter += 26
            result += chr(new_letter)

        else:
            result += chr(letter)

    return result
```

Comment: What does `o % 26` do?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Modulo operations should be familiar to anyone who has done any amount of programming, and very easy to look up in any basic Python introduction.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed, that's *why* I was asking. `o % 26` doesn't make sense, it converts the offset in `o` to 0..25`. If `o` is a character you basically get a random value back (as it depends on the offset of the character `a`). If it is a number then it should simply return an error instead, you don't want to accept -27 or 1000 as a key.

Comment: So, a hint? Maybe mark it as such, then; too often, commenters ask for clarification where they are too lazy to find out what something means.

Answer (score 0):

You were halfway there. You handled `if new_letter < 26` but didn't handle the cases where `new_letter > 26`

Edit: By the way, look at the values returned by ord(i). You'll notice that 26 isn't the correct number to be checking against

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I suppose that is a number for shifts.

Comment: Would a better number be ord("a") or 97?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `o` is the number of shifts. You need to make sure ord is between `a` and `z`.

```
    # truncate overflowing
    while new_letter < ord("a"):
        new_letter += 26
    # however, case above never shows up. Why?
    while new_letter > ord("z"):
        new_letter -= 26
    result += chr(new_letter)
```

Where you'll find out:

```
>> ord("a") # the base is not 26!
97
```

Comment: I thought I was checking if ord(i) was between a and z. It'll never be less than "a" because in regards of letters lowercase "a" would be the lowest value I believe. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Liv you may vote or accept my answer if it helps. Thanks.